# Restrict access to particular pages for non-authenticated users

Tags: django

I'm building a simple forum in Django and I've got two models - Topic and Subtopic. I need to restrict access to some topics and subtopics for non-authenticated users, so that they couldn't access them, while other topics and subtopics should remain accessible to all the users -- both authenticated and anonymous. For example, I've got topic **Sports** with subtopic **Football** and topic **Management** with subtopic **HR**. While the first one should be accessible to all the users, the second one should be accessible only to the authenticated ones. How do I achieve that? 
Here are my dashboard (where all the topics are listed) and subtopic views:

```
def dashboard(request):
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'djangoforum/dashboard.html', {'topics': topics})

def subtopic_view(request, slug):
    current_user = request.user
    form = ThreadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    subtopic = get_object_or_404(SubTopic, slug=slug)
    threads = Thread.objects.filter(subtopic=subtopic, ancestor_id=None).order_by('-created_date')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            thread = form.save(commit=False)
            thread.subtopic = subtopic
            thread.save()
            return redirect(request.path)
    return render(request, 'djangoforum/subtopic.html', {
        'current_user': current_user,
        'form': form,
        'subtopic': subtopic,
        'threads': threads
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you need to set object level permission and for that you can make use of [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian) or [django-rules](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules)

Answer (score 0):

Use `@login_required` decorator in view that will restrict to access that view via annoymous user

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'djangoforum/dashboard.html', {'topics': topics})
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

Comment: but the thing is that for example, I've got topic Sports with subtopic Football and topic Management with subtopic HR. While the first one should be accessible to all the users, the second one should be accessible only to the authenticated ones.